# How to make arbor.js work on Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser, arbor.js

I have developed neo4j web interface using [Arbor.js](http://arborjs.org). Later i found it is not displaying the graph in any version of Internet Explorer, not even in IE10.

While searching in google came to this [website](http://www.instagrok.com/grok/grok?query=internet%20explorer) and they are showing the arbor graph in IE. Can any tell me how to make arbor.js work on IE.

Comment: not working in IE9 for sure and seems to use non standard dom api.

Comment: [This fork](https://github.com/ende76/arbor) has fixes for IE9+

Comment: Thanks @FélixSaparelli, if you can write it as an answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking on GitHub, I discovered [a fork by ende76](https://github.com/ende76/arbor) which contains fixes for IE9+. I haven't tested it, though. Also see [this pull request](https://github.com/samizdatco/arbor/pull/11) which has another branch with different IE fixes, and look tested (as of 2 years ago). There are two other issues ([[9](https://github.com/samizdatco/arbor/issues/9)], [[13](https://github.com/samizdatco/arbor/pull/13)]) open which have some comments on IE8/9 compatibility.

However, you might want to look at choosing a different library. Besides the obvious disadvantages in using an unsupported and [apparently abandoned](https://github.com/samizdatco/arbor/issues/23) library, there are [various](https://github.com/samizdatco/arbor/issues/7) [issues](https://github.com/samizdatco/arbor/issues/10) [detailing](https://github.com/samizdatco/arbor/issues/15) [performance](https://github.com/samizdatco/arbor/issues/18) [and](https://github.com/samizdatco/arbor/issues/22) [stability](https://github.com/samizdatco/arbor/issues/36) [issues](https://github.com/samizdatco/arbor/issues) in other browsers.